# How to find which list contains a specific value

Tags: java

Assume we have a list of lists such as:

```
[3,5],[2,9],[4,1],[8,5]
```

I would like to get the lists that contain the value 5. I know using the method `contains()` will return true or false but doesn't return which list contains this value.

What is the solution to this question?

Comment: Write a loop (or two). Make an attempt. Try something. See what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
 list.stream().filter(el -> el.contains(5)).findFirst()
```

Answer (score 0):

To return all the sub-lists you can combine `filter` with `collect`:

```
List<List<Integer>> listsWith5 = list.stream()
   .filter(sub -> sub.contains(5))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
listOfLists.add(Arrays.asList(3, 5));
listOfLists.add(Arrays.asList(2, 9));
listOfLists.add(Arrays.asList(4, 1));
listOfLists.add(Arrays.asList(8, 5));
List<List<Integer>> listOfListsContaingValue = listOfLists.stream().filter(p -> 
    p.contains(5)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a single loop, no need for "fancy" streams:

```
List<Integer> targets = new ArrayList<>();
for(List<Integer> subList : lists) {
    if(subList.contains(5)) {
        targets.add(subList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need the indices of the lists containing 5 in the original list:

```
int[] indicesOfInnerListsWith5 = IntStream.range(0, myList.size()).
    filter(i->myList.get(i).contains(5)).toArray();
```